# The predicted value is no variance when I use trained caffemodel for regression

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

I use below code to call trained caffemodel to predict values.Unfortunately, the Results is no variance when I change Factors's data. Can someone help me

```
std::string ModelFilePath = "net_csv_hdf5_for_prediction.prototxt";
std::string WeightFilePath = "rt_hdf5_iter_5000.caffemodel";
float Factors[] = { -0.007, 0.207, -0.071, -0.007, -0.009, ...}; // here I ignore other 304 data
std::vector<float> Descriptors(Factors, Factors + sizeof(Factors) / sizeof(float));
CPredictedTest PredictedTest(ModelFilePath, WeightFilePath, 1);
std::vector<float> Results = PredictedTest.predict(Descriptors);
```

here is my net model text--net_csv_hdf5_for_prediction.prototxt:

```
name: "CSVNet"
layer {
name: "framert"
type: "Input"
top: "data"
input_param {
    shape {
        dim: 1 dim: 1 dim: 1 dim: 309
    }
}
}
layer {
name: "inner1"
type: "InnerProduct"
bottom: "data"
top: "inner1"
param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1.0
}
param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
}
inner_product_param {
    num_output: 500
    weight_filler {
        type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
        type: "constant"
        value: 0.1
    }
}
}
layer {
name: "sigmoid1"
type: "Sigmoid"
bottom: "inner1"
top: "sigmoid1"
}
layer {
name: "inner2"
type: "InnerProduct"
bottom: "sigmoid1"
top: "inner2"
param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1.0
}
param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
}
inner_product_param {
    num_output: 400 
    weight_filler {
        type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
        type: "constant"
        value: 0.1
    }
}
}
layer {
name: "sigmoid2"
type: "Sigmoid"
bottom: "inner2"
top: "sigmoid2"
}
layer {
name: "inner3"
type: "InnerProduct"
bottom: "sigmoid2"
top: "inner3"
param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1.0
}
param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
}
inner_product_param {
    num_output: 300
    weight_filler {
        type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
        type: "constant"
        value: 0.1
    }
}
}
layer {
name: "sigmoid3"
type: "Sigmoid"
bottom: "inner3"
top: "sigmoid3"
}
layer {
name: "inner4"
type: "InnerProduct"
bottom: "sigmoid3"
top: "inner4"
param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1.0
}
param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
}
inner_product_param {
    num_output: 200
    weight_filler {
        type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
        type: "constant"
        value: 0.1
    }
}
}
layer {
name: "sigmoid4"
type: "Sigmoid"
bottom: "inner4"
top: "sigmoid4"
}
layer {
name: "inner5"
type: "InnerProduct"
bottom: "sigmoid4"
top: "inner5"
param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1.0
}
param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
}
inner_product_param {
    num_output: 100
    weight_filler {
        type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
        type: "constant"
        value: 0.1
    }
}
}
layer {
name: "sigmoid5"
type: "Sigmoid"
bottom: "inner5"
top: "sigmoid5"
}
layer {
name: "inner6"
type: "InnerProduct"
bottom: "sigmoid5"
top: "inner6"
param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1.0
}
param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
}
inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1
    weight_filler {
        type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
        type: "constant"
        value: 0.1
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you include information on how you trained the data?

Comment: The train net model you can see here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395892/why-most-of-the-predicted-results-are-0-when-i-use-a-caffe-bp-regression-model)

Comment: I guess most possibly there are some `sigmoid` units getting saturated due to large input values. So maybe scale the input, or substract mean can help.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have scaled the input data, and I have tried the other active function TanH.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably occurs when you train your model. What are you using as your input? How many examples did you train with? What where the outputs? How did the accuracy and loss evolve with the training? What is your loss function?

By the way, the sizes of the dimensions are too large. Your input only has a size of 309. The sizes of the blobs within your network shouldn't need to ever get larger than this.

Comment: thanks for help.As you say the error maybe occurs in my train model, but the results will change and be accepted when I test my test data set by using my train net model.

Comment: Why the blobs should not large than the data set dimension? The other classmate has use similar net model in r and his result is well.Actually, his  neurons in inner layer is large than input data set dimension.